# Novel describing long-distance transport where only soul is transferred

Tags: story-identification, novel

My wife is looking for a story, most probably a novel, where a mode for long-distance transport for people is transferring only the "soul" into a new body. The original body is eliminated after the transfer.

She read the novel in the 1980s or shortly after, but it could be considerably older. The main character was probably a woman. Unfortunately, we do not have more details.

The only plot detail my wife remembers is the main character contemplating this transport technology and whether there is a soul. After the first time she(?) uses the transport from Earth to another planet she is convinced "yes, there is a soul."

The story was most probably in English, or with low probability German. It could also have been part of a series.

Comment: Hi there! :) well, it would still be worth a try to take a look at [this guide on how to ask a good story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), you never know, maybe that'll trigger some more memories to edit!

Comment: Was the novel part of a series?  Except for eliminating the original body (which sometimes happened by accident, but wasn't the intent) this resembles the Cluster series by Piers Anthony.

Comment: The form of transport you mention is what is used in ["Waystation" by Clifford D. Simak.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Way_Station_(novel)) That is the only similarity though, I can't leave this as a comment as I've yet to reach 50 reputation.

Comment: I think I've read this also. The woman protagonist was the main scientist who invented this transporter but ( I think!) She is very reluctant to use it herself because of the soul issues. As it becomes widespread and very cheap she finds herself getting more and more socially isolated. It was a fairly long short story in an anthology I read in the late eighties but the actual book could have been older ...hope these memories help